What is the molecular flux on a MOVING wall?
The maxwell distribution for the $x$ component of velocity is $f(v_x)$.
I know that the flux for a stationary wall is given by
$$\int_0^\infty nv_x f(v_x)\ dv_x$$
Which is equal to $nv_\text{avg}/4$     where $v_\text{avg}$ is the average speed of the molecules ($\sqrt{8kT/\pi m}$).
What is the flux for a moving wall with $u\ll v_\text{avg}$?
Here is my approach: only particles with $v_\text{avg}>u$ can reach the wall, and the relative velocity of the particles that reach the wall is $v_x - u$.   So flux = $$\int_u^\infty n(v_x-u) f(v_x)\ dv_x$$
Which results in $n(v_\text{avg}-2u)/4$  (in the first order of u)
I've checked the calculations five times to assure that this is indeed the result of the integral and made wolframalpha take it as well.
The thing that threw me off was that in my past 5 years of olympiad experience, I've always used $n(v_\text{avg}-u)/4$   for tasks involving the flux and It has always worked. The official solutions to questions involving this also does the same thing, and even at the first European Physics Olympiad, the best solution took $dN$ to be $Sn(v_\text{avg}-u)dt/6.$
Is the integral and the result $n(v_\text{avg}-2u)/4$ above wrong?    Also if anyone knows a paper that derives this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Please use MathJax for the formulas. I have done it for the first few lines to give you a start.
